# Customize FinancialIndicator

Tags: plotting, charts, finance

I have a set of financial data in a 5-minutes (download [here](https://pastebin.com/6xH1YfPi)) and 1-day timeframe (download [here](https://pastebin.com/vcHUVjUs))

Since the ordering of my dataset is different than the ordering taken by `TradingChart`, this is how I handle the data before plotting them with `TradingChart`

```
dataImported5mins=Import["5mins.csv"];
dataImported5mins = Map[{#[[1]], {#[[4]], #[[3]], #[[2]], #[[5]], Quantity[#[[6]], "shares"]}} &, dataImported5mins];

dataImportedDaily=Import["daily.csv"];
dataImportedDaily = Map[{#[[1]], {#[[4]], #[[3]], #[[2]], #[[5]], Quantity[#[[6]], "shares"]}} &, dataImportedDaily];

dataPlot=TradingChart[dataImported5mins]
```

I want to use the 1-day data to compute the Central Pivot Range ([CPR](https://www.stockmaniacs.net/central-pivot-range/)) to apply at the 5-minutes chart.

The Central Pivot Range is made of three main levels (called TC,Pivot,BC) that are constant during the day. They are calculated as follow

Pivot = (High + Low + Close)/3

BC = (High + Low)/2

TC = 2*Pivot – BC

where High,Low,Close are the values of the previous daily candlestick.

How can I create my own `FinancialIndicator` to add to the `TradingChart`?

For example, the daily candle of August, 16 has

```
 {open,high,low,close,volume} = {46134, 48750, 45292.8, 45809.7,Quantity[1.22446*10^6, "Shares"]}
```

therefore the pivot levels that should appear on the candles of the August 17th in the 5-minutes time frame should be

```
PIVOT=(48750+45292.8+45809.7)/3 = 46617.5
BC = (48750+45292.8)/2=47021.4
TC = 2*PIVOT - BC = 46213.6
```

How can I do this efficiently?

For example, on TradingView I see something like the following chart

[image]

where the blue lines are the pivot, BC and TC.

Comment: Do you want to apply the yesterdayCPR to a single 5minFrame or to all 5minFrames of the actual day?

Comment: @hieron not sure I understood - what do you mean?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me if the Central Pivot Range is layed over a single 5minFrame, so I think those 5minFrames are accumulated and represented in one plot of a 24hFrame, means 5min * 12 * 24 gives 288 5minFrames in one plot, is this correct? Your import contains 288 records (rows) and the other import contains 1 record from yesterday.